# Can't extract URL property from applescript variable (Safari)

Tags: safari, applescript

I ain't flash with any of this...so I hope the following is sufficient.

I want to get the properties from the current Safari tab and then use them later
in my script. On doing the below:

```
tell application "Safari"
set pageInfo to properties of current tab of window 1
end tell

set subJect to name of pageInfo
set urlName to URL of pageInfo
```

subJect is assigned a value but urlName is not, and I get an error saying

> "Can’t get URL of {name:\"Can't extract URL property from applescript variable - Stack Overflow\", URL:\"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=cant%20extract%20url%20applescript%20object\", index:6, visible:true, class:tab}." number -1728 from URL of {class:«class bTab», name:"Can't extract URL property from applescript variable - Stack Overflow", URL:"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=cant%20extract%20url%20applescript%20object", index:6, visible:true}

What is my problem here?
I just want to be able to assign the properties to a "variable" and then access them

Cheers,
CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applescript is having trouble with URL. If you notice it's blue in color in the applescript editor window which means it's a keyword to applescript. I believe that's the problem you're having. As such just move these 2 lines inside the Safari tell block and it should work because Safari understands how to use URL for this purpose. Of course once you have urlName you can use that variable outside the tell block.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set pageInfo to properties of current tab of window 1
    set subJect to name of pageInfo
    set urlName to URL of pageInfo
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks regulus6633, that was all i had to do.

Comment: Not fully sure I understand why though - I assume it's because of the standard additions URL class. 

In general, if I have a list with records, is it impossible to extract any record that shares a name with a reserved word?

Comment: Sometimes you run into these conflicts and sometimes not. The best is to just avoid possible conflicts. For example if you create your own record and you wanted to have a "name" quantity, it's best not to use name because of possible conflicts. The way around that is either use something else like theName or use it like |name|.

Comment: Really though applications and applescript keywords mix all the time and cause these conflicts. It's best to extract record properties from within the application that generated the record to avoid the conflicts. In your example "name" worked outside of safari but URL didn't... so you just never know when a conflict will arise. Just be aware of it and you can figure out a solution as we've discovered here.

Comment: No worries. Thanks very much for your help and taking time out of yer day for me.

Cheers!